# i am getting error when i use jw-pagination or ngx-pagination...I am using angular 9.1.1

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, angular9, ngx-pagination

**jw-pagination**

ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:49:5 - error NG6001: Cannot declare 'JwPaginationComponent' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.

**ngx-pagiation**

ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:49:5 - error NG6001: Cannot declare 'NgxPaginationModule' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't declare anything in the declarations* **(in @NgModule of app.module.ts file)** if you don't have it in your app.

So,

1. Just remove the declaration of 'JwPaginationComponent' or 'NgxPaginationModule' from the @NgModule of app.module.ts file.
2. and add 'JwPaginationComponent' or 'NgxPaginationModule' in the imports **(in @NgModule of app.module.ts file)**.

Now try ng serve, it should work fine...